# Find value in nested object in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection with following structure:

```
"speed": {
      "m198": [
        {
          "speed": ["60","150"],
          "channels": {
            "push": {
              "timings": {
                "from": "00:00",
                "to": "23:59",
                "delay": 600
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "speed": [ "50","60"],
          "channels": {
            "push": {
              "timings": {
                "from": "00:00",
                "to": "23:59",
                "delay": 600
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "speed": ["60", "100"],
          "channels": {
            "sms": {
              "timings": {
                "from": "00:00",
                "to": "23:59",
                "delay": 600
              },
              "sendTo": [
                "1234567890"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

I would like to query this document to get all the records which have `push` in the `channels`. I have tried using the `$in()` function of MongoDB but have not been able to get the exact results.

Comment: Not clear what you mean here by "get all the records". Better to show your expected results and what you are looking to match for.

Comment: Use `$exists` instead of `$in`. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

Comment: `{"speed.m198.channels.push":{$exists:true}}`  though it will only work if you know m198

Comment: @Undefined_variable Here m198 is a variable field which will change in every document. So I cannot directly look for m198.channels

Comment: This really goes down to bad data model. If you cannot change the data model try doing the required operation using javascript function